# C# | Changing the size of the consoles buffer below what was initially set

Tags: c#, console, console-application, buffer

I'm wondering if its possible to change the size of the consoles buffer, as the included Console.SetBufferSize function will not allow you to shrink the buffer. bonus points if I don't need a external library.

Comment: Has this question been solved?

Comment: @Longoon12000 whopps! yes it has, ill close it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation of Console.SetBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setbuffersize?view=netframework-4.8) it is not limited to growing the buffer. However you have to adjust the console window size before shrinking the buffer.

This example works:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Current buffer size: {Console.BufferWidth}x{Console.BufferHeight}");
Console.SetWindowSize(1, 1);
Console.SetBufferSize(80, 80);
Console.SetWindowSize(40, 20);
Console.WriteLine($"New buffer size: {Console.BufferWidth}x{Console.BufferHeight}");
```

Output:

> Current buffer size: 120x9001
>   New buffer size: 80x80